# Webcam streaming client to client

Tags: javascript, php, nginx, rtmp, http-live-streaming

The task is that the client `A` can stream from web camera to other clients `B`, `C`, etc via server `S`.

I configured the **HLS** streaming server using **NGINX** + **nginx-rtmp-module**. It works fine. Now my server can do streaming. Executing this command on the server I create the stream.

```
$ ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/stream
```

This command captures the webcam and creates a stream that is accessible by URL: `rtmp://localhost:1935/live/stream`.

And now I can watch this stream in any video player.

But I need to capture video from browser of the client `A` and transfer it to the url `rtmp://localhost:1935/live/stream` to create a stream.

In JS script I capture the stream from the web camera and display it in `<video>` tag.

**HTM**L code:

```
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <video controls muted></video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS** code:

```
let recordingPlayer = $('video');
let videoStream = null;

let successCallback = function (stream) {
    recordingPlayer[0].srcObject = stream;
    recordingPlayer[0].play();

    videoStream = stream;

    // I think I need to somehow transfer this stream to the address:
    // rtmp://localhost:1935/live/stream
};

let errorCallback = function (error) {
    console.log(error);
};

let mediaConstraints = { video: true, audio: true };

// Doing webcam capture
navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(mediaConstraints)
    .then(successCallback)
    .catch(errorCallback);
```

But I absolutely can not understand how I can transfer the stream from the client `A` webcam to the my **HLS** streaming server.

As I understand, the `ffmpeg` command captures video from the server webcam, then converts it to the suitable format (mp4 with video codec libx264), then sends data to this url `rtmp://localhost:1935/live/stream`.

I think I need to send the stream from the web camera to the server using web sockets, and then on the server, using that command `ffmpeg`, send data to that address.

Can you please help me, how to send captured stream from the webcam to the **HLS** streaming server?

Comment: Hummm not sure to understand what you mean by *Client `A` browser*, but have you thought about using WebRTC?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I mean that user A goes to the site. He presses the "Start Stream" button. Next, need to somehow send the stream from the client webcam to the server.